# Can't connect to my email server

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, dovecot

Recently I transferred my domain to NoIP, and I had to create a mail server.

(I had to transfer to noip because I can't setup a static/fixed ip as I am particular not a business, and I don't have a business taxpayer number to get a business line in my ISP...)

But I can't connect to it in my email client.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

I assigned/forwarded/opened IMAP, SMTP, POP, and LDAP ports to my Ubuntu Machine in my router:

And I created a mx record in cr7akg.com: `cr7akg.com 10` :

[Images](https://meocloud.pt/link/fd0954be-8d60-44fb-9516-37b4898df4c0/Images%20EmailServer/)

The output of `telnet cr7akg.com 25` and `telnet cr7akg.com smtp` are:

```
Trying 85.245.177.97...
telnet: connect to address 85.245.177.97: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

What I'm missing?
Why I can't connect to email server with my email client?

Output of `sudo netstat -panet`

```
Ligações de Internet Activas (servidores e estabelecidos)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Endereço Local          Endereço Remoto         Estado       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7300            0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      1001       12435       1231/perl       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      117        95382       7965/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.104:27754     0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      1001       12434       1231/perl       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      0          138499      18957/sendmail: MTA
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      0          103425      9641/vsftpd     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      0          11938       1480/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      0          10481       940/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      0          205310      9231/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      0          138498      18957/sendmail: MTA
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      1000       212857      10119/4         
tcp        0    264 192.168.1.104:22        192.168.1.90:62312      ESTABELECIDO 0          213850      10052/sshd: diogosa
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.104:48086     88.81.132.153:7301      ESTABELECIDO 1001       166071      1231/perl       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    ESCUTA      0          123277      7474/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    ESCUTA      0          10483       940/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    ESCUTA      0          205309      9231/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    ESCUTA      1000       212856      10119/4
```

Update:

I removed sendmail:

```
Ligações de Internet Activas (servidores e estabelecidos)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Endereço Local          Endereço Remoto         Estado       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7300            0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      1001       11794       1373/perl       
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.104:27754     0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      1001       11793       1373/perl       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      117        11580       1227/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      0          9180        1137/master     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      0          11664       1550/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      0          8827        887/vsftpd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      0          8843        876/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      0          15897       2344/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      0          9174        1137/master     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      1000       15993       2387/4          
tcp        0    264 192.168.1.104:22        192.168.1.90:62541      ESTABELECIDO 0          15931       2351/sshd: diogosar
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    ESCUTA      0          9181        1137/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    ESCUTA      0          11125       1330/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    ESCUTA      0          8845        876/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    ESCUTA      0          15896       2344/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    ESCUTA      0          9175        1137/master     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    ESCUTA      1000       15992       2387/4          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:56645               ::1:631                 ESTABELECIDO 0          15325       1110/cups-browsed
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 ::1:56645               ESTABELECIDO 0          15909       2344/cupsd
```

Output of `sudo iptables -L -vnx:`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: `netstat -panet` and `iptables -L -vnx` output would help. Did you check with tcpdump if any traffic actually reaches your server?

Comment: Ports 21, 53, 80 and some others are open. So the problem are only the mailing ports. Maybe your provider is blocking those?

Comment: Not sure about ISPs in Portugal but most here in US (unless it is a business tier) don't allow inbound to port 25. The previous comment by @sebix is correct-- your port 25 is blocked at your ISP.

Comment: @Arul port 25 isn't blocked, check images link please... and I was on the phone with they (ISP (Portugal Telecom)) and they tell me that I can these ports in my router...

Comment: @sebix How do you check what ports are open? when you check maybe you see port 443 (HTTPS) blocked/closed, but really not closed because I haven't anything that uses that port.. but if I configure HTTPS in apache then you will see open... the same thing to mail server, maybe bad configuration??

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva If your ISP confirmed they are not blocking port 25,  then the problem might be in your router configuration. Are you sure you have your router configured to forward port 25 traffic to your server running postfix? Try this command "nmap -p21,25,80 -sT cr7akg.com" you will notice 21 and 80 are open while 25 is closed.

Comment: @Arul please help me :'(

Comment: @sebix please help me :'(

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva do you realize your service is working now (not sure what all you did)... Botom-line is, now that your smtp service is listening on physical interface on port 25 it is reachable from anywhere. I just connected to your mail server :) --- check your log for my IP. If you want, I can send you a test message

Comment: How, I only removed sendmail...

Comment: How do you connect to my mail server? you guessed the password? or I am outdated

Comment: @Arul I can't send mail from cr7akg.com but smtp is on: Relay access denied

Comment: @Arul Also IMAP is not working...

Comment: I strongly suggest to learn some linux, networking and mail basics before addressing this task.

Comment: ISP for residential do not want mail servers in their environments.  How about you get a virtual machine in a multitenet cloud that's cheap and do it there?

Comment: @PaulDelasaux Do you recommend anything those? cheapest possible...  I already have so much expenses

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can possibly have followed the tutorial you link to, since (a) sendmail is running as your MTA, and (b) it's only listening on `127.0.0.1`.  That latter is why you can't connect to port 25 from anywhere else.

To change this, look for the line

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
```

in `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`, change it to

```
dnlDAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')
```

or just delete it in its entirety.  Remake your config file with `make sendmail.cf` and restart the service with `service sendmail restart`.  Confirm that the MTA is now listening on all addresses with `netstat -apn|grep -w 25`; you want to see something like

```
tcp        0      0 :::25             :::*             LISTEN      8525/sendmail
```

Note the change in column four (all these commands will require privilege).  Then you should be able to contact your MTA from the internet-at-large, always assuming (as others have pointed out) that you're not trying from an endpoint which can't talk to the SMTP port by ISP default.

**Edit**: you have now removed sendmail and installed postfix, and your server is now listening on all ports (see `netstat` output above).  Your server is reachable from the internet at large:

```
[me@risby ~]$ telnet cr7akg.com 25
Trying 85.245.177.97...
Connected to cr7akg.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 Ubuntu ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
```

So you've solved your problem.

Comment: I followed, I sure, but I also configured sendmail

Comment: That is not a small variance from the article.  You would do **much** better to tell us what you actually did, and better still not to change things without understanding them.

Comment: But I'm saying the true, also I will delete --purge sendmail I don't need it anymore What I need it's a mail server... I followed this tutorial: https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql and later this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassasin

Comment: Maybe this : GRANT SELECT ON mailserver.* TO 'mailuser'@'__127.0.0.1__' IDENTIFIED BY '**********';

Comment: MadHatter please help me :'(

Comment: no,  **I posted this thread after I installed postfix and dovecot**, and next removed sendmail

Comment: Yes (not no!). MadHatter is right. Anyone doing `telnet cr7akg.com 25` gets a response from Postfix. I just tried it. Maybe you didn't wait long enough for your DNS cache to expire after changing some records?.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are running your mail server only on loop back interface (I assume there are no other entries for :25 on your netstat output above)

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      0          138498      18957/sendmail: MTA
```

It is not reachable for anything outside of the host. It should run on your physical interface the router is forwarding to.